# Query params in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, rest, request, alamofire

In my iOS app I use Alamofire 4 and wanna send request to back-end with query params. but Alamofire convert the "?" to "%3F" in url query (http://blahblahblah/mobile-proxy/authorizations%3FphoneNumber=+555555555&userID=agent) and I get 404 error from backend. I read about URLEncoding, but I can't find any way how I can use it with URLRequest, because I use custom router enum file with URLRequest. This is a part of my Router file:

```
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

        let url = try Router.baseUrl.asURL()

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

        switch self {

        case .authorizations:
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.setValue(getHeaderCredentials().operationID, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.operationID)
            urlRequest.setValue(getHeaderCredentials().appCode, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.appCode)
        case .startAuthentication, .startContractOperation:
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.setValue(getHeaderCredentials().appCode, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.appCode)
        case .operationAllowance:
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        default:
            break
        }

        switch self {

        case .authorizations:
            urlRequest = try Alamofire.URLEncoding.queryString.encode(urlRequest, with: nil)
        default:
            break
        }

        return urlRequest
    }
```

I try Alamofire.URLEncoding.queryString.encode, but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to create string of your url and set URLEncoding like

```
let urlwithPercent = yourURlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed())
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlwithPercent))
```

here yourURlString is a full url as string (http://blahblahblah/mobile-proxy/authorizations%3FphoneNumber=+555555555&userID=agent)